# How to save filtered image in array?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, core-image, imagefilter

I have an UICollectionView(horizontal) and putted there, in cells, images with applied filters.

I did this:

```
var filtered = [Int: UIImage]()
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("filterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! filterCell

    let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        let img = self.image!
        let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in

            if let filtered = self.filtered[indexPath.row] {
                cell.imageView.image = self.filtered[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                self.filtered[indexPath.row] = img1
                cell.imageView.image = self.filtered[indexPath.row]

            }
        })
    }

    self.queue!.addOperation(op1);

    return cell
}
```

where:

```
var myFilter = CIFilter()
func applyFilterTo(image: UIImage, filter: String) -> UIImage {
    let sourceImage = CIImage(image: image)

    myFilter = CIFilter(name: filter)!
    myFilter.setDefaults()

    myFilter.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(myFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: myFilter.outputImage!.extent)

    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: outputCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

    return newImage
}
```

So the principle here is applying my filter to the image, save it in my dictionary and later on scroll load images from the dictionary. But it still takes images, applies filters and just later shows it. So on scroll my UICollectionView freezes, filters on images change.

What I do wrong and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to do `let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])` if image already in `self.filtered[indexPath.row]`?

So I think you should check `if let filtered = self.filtered[indexPath.row] {` and if not, just then start filter it.

For your code it will be something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("filterCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! filterCell

    if let filtered = self.filtered[indexPath.row] {
      cell.imageView.image = filtered
    } else {
      let op1 = NSBlockOperation { () -> Void in
        let img = self.image!
        let img1 = self.applyFilterTo(img, filter: self.filtersImages[indexPath.row])

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
          self.filtered[indexPath.row] = img1
          cell.imageView.image = self.filtered[indexPath.row]
        })
      }

      self.queue!.addOperation(op1);
    }

  return cell
}
```